# How to add the open source license acknowledgments from .md to ios app's acknowledgments

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, open-source

I am working on application which use open source libraries,I am wondering that where and how should i add the open source license acknowledgments from .md to ios app's acknowledgments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at: [iOS-AcknowledgementGenerator](https://github.com/cvknage/iOS-AcknowledgementGenerator)

It's a small script I made in Ruby to help out whit displaying open source licence acknowledgements in your apps settings bundle.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on github may meet your require:

[AttributedMarkdowne](https://github.com/dreamwieber/AttributedMarkdown)(Native Markdown Parsing to NSAttributedString on iOS)